# After using Angular2+ RouteReuseStrategy, how to call a method in return to cache components to update part?

Tags: angular2-routing

I have a list page, and click a column to enter the details page. Edit and return. Because using RouteReuseStrategy, it can maintain the list page of the scene remains the same. But I'd like to partially update, However, I don't know how to trigger it.

Here is my RouteReuseStrategy service and most of the same.

```
export class SimpleReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

_cacheRouters: { [key: string]: any } = {};

shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return true;
}
store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    this._cacheRouters[route.routeConfig.path] = {
        snapshot: route,
        handle: handle
    };
}
shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return !!this._cacheRouters[route.routeConfig.path];
}
retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    return this._cacheRouters[route.routeConfig.path].handle;
}
shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: 
ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your list page component you can listen to route changes:

- Detect if the navigation start came from the detail route i.e. /detail/1

  - if so, get the 'id' param of the route /detail/1
  - replace that element in the list

```js
// List component

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.subscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      // checkIfDetailPage and store ID
  }

  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      // checkIfThisPage and get the ID
      // replace element with ID
  }
});
}
```

An alternative approach for detecting something changed (instead of observing the route changes) you could implement Service to which your list component subscribes and your detail component notifies.